# 4 spoons and 3 forks cost 15. 4 dollars. 4 spoons and 1 forks cost 13 dollars. Find the cost of 5 forks?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My kid needs help with her math hw. It has been a while.

4 spoons and 3 forks cost 15. 4 dollars. 4 spoons and 1 forks cost 13 dollars. Find the cost of 5 forks?

Find the cost of 5 forks?

Here is my solution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn5Yh.png)

Is it right?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Why do you doubt your answer? Your daughter can probably understand how you set up the two equations. Will she understand how you solved them?

Comment: I assume they are learning about matrices??

Comment: John, what is the subject of the present maths teachings she gets?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I suspect your child is learning about matrices--it's unfortunate that they have been given such a simple problem (yet I suspect that's on purpose to allow them to "understand"--which they won't anyway, in high school).

You need to first set up the system of linear equations--matrices *only* work when it's a system of *linear* equations:

$$
4s + 3f = 15 \\
4s + 1f = 13
$$

This translates into the matrix problem:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4&3 \\
4&1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
s \\
f
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
15 \\
13
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To solve this problem you take the inverse of the left-side matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s \\
f
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
4&3 \\
4&1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
15 \\
13
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To find the inverse is a bit involved and I doubt that a Pre-Calculus course explains how to find an inverse...instead they are probably just supposed to use the formula for a $2\times 2$ matrix (or maybe even just type it into the calculator...which is quite possible, in which case the below will be way over your daughter's head probably):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b \\
d&c
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} =  \frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For your matrix, that's:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
4&3 \\
4&1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} =&\  \frac{1}{4\cdot 1-4\cdot 3}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 \\
-4 & 4
\end{bmatrix} \\
=&\ \frac{1}{4-12}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 \\
-4 & 4
\end{bmatrix} \\
=&\ -\frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 \\
-4 & 4
\end{bmatrix} \\
=&\ \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} \\
\frac{4}{8} & -\frac{4}{8}
\end{bmatrix} \\
=&\ \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} \\
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

So now, the result would be:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
s \\
f
\end{bmatrix} =&\ 
\begin{bmatrix}
15 \\
13
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
4&3 \\
4&1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \\
=&\ 
\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} \\
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
15 \\
13
\end{bmatrix} \\
=&\ \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{8}\cdot 15 + \frac{3}{8}\cdot 13  \\
\frac{1}{2}\cdot 15  -\frac{1}{2}\cdot 13
\end{bmatrix}\\
=&\ \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-15 + 39}{8}  \\
\frac{15 - 13}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
=&\ \begin{bmatrix} \frac{24}{8}  \\
\frac{2}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
=&\ \begin{bmatrix} 3  \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

So we have:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s \\
f
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\longrightarrow
s = 3, f = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

From the image, you could subtract the second line from the first line to get 2F = 2 => F = 1.

This might make more sense than using matrices which 'hide' the variable names, since matrices are (perfectly usable but) more simplifying when there are many variables/large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a graphical solution. Each equation gives an affine hyperplane, here: lines.

The intersection holds the solutions, here: point $A$.

[image]

Comment: If a child can understand the meaning of "affine hyperplane," I would imagine they should not have any difficulty solving a linear system of two equations in two unknowns!  ^_^

Comment: You can be sloppy and call it linear function. :-)

Comment: @mvw I don't think you got the point of the comment...

Comment: @Jared That is possible. The problem we have here is that we actually do not know what background the daughter has. I believe a graphical presentation of the conditions and feasible solutions is easy to understand. Of course I would not use certain expressions.

Comment: @mvw When the question starts out as "My kid...", I think it's pretty safe to assume this is not a graduate level Math course and thus "affine hyperplane" would _not_ be in the vocabulary.